# eclipse(Java) 'Create a Hello World SWT application' found under welcome>tutorials

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

My current issue is as follows:

1) I DLed the eclipse for Java developers(running java 8 SE on 64bit, windows 8), attempting to complete 'Create a Hello World SWT application' found under welcome>tutorials.

2) Under step 3, titled: Import the SWT project; the directions are as follows:

> Open the Import wizard from the main menu via File > Import..., and
>   select Plug-in Development > Plug-ins and Fragments. Click Next.
>
> On the Import Plug-ins and Fragments page, select  Import from: The
>   active target platform. Plug-ins and Fragments to import: Select from
>   all plug-ins and fragments found at specified location. Import As:
>   Projects with source folders. Click Next.
>
> On the Selection page, Add org.eclipse.swt.{platform}.{os}.{arch} (for
>   example: org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86 for win32) to Plug-ins and
>   Fragments to Import: list. Click Finish.
>
> This will create the org.eclipse.swt.{platform}.{os}.{arch} project
>   which we will need to compile and run the application.

3)The first issue I'm having is that, when I open file>Import, I do not see Plug-in Development> Plug-ins and Fragments.  When I open file>Import, I see the following folders: General, CVS, Git, Install, Maven, Run/Debug, Tasks, Team, XML.

4) When I select the "?" to the right of this information, a window opens with the following information:

Importing existing projects

> You can use the Import Wizard to command link import an existing
>   project into workspace.
>
> 1. From the main menu bar, select command link File > Import.... The Import wizard opens.
> 2. Select General > Existing Project into Workspace and click Next.
> 3. Choose either Select root directory or Select archive file and click the associated Browse to locate the directory or file containing
>      the projects.
> 4. Under Projects select the project or projects which you would like to import.
> 5. Click Finish to start the import

5) I should mention that at this point I have already created a new Java project called HelloWorldSWTApplication, I have not yet made a package or class for this project.  So in my Package Explorer, in the above mentioned project folder, only src and JRE System Library exist.

6) When following the directions given under the title "Importing existing projects", the directions that appear when the "?" is selected, I have selected General>Existing Project into Workspace>Select root directory>clicked the associated Browse to locate the directory or file>Browse For Folder>workspace>HelloWorldSWTApplication>OK.
However, I get the following warning message:

> Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace.

In the projects field, I can see the folder name and the path, but they are ghosted-out, I can not select them, can not select Finish.

Questions:  What am I/Have I done wrong?  How might I fix one or all of these issues?

Comment: Are you sure the java developers version comes with the plugin packages?  (I haven't touched that one in years)  I know eclipse classic comes with the plugin projects so perhaps give that one a try.

Comment: Good question, I'm unsure.  Is that something that the eclipse EE would have?

Comment: Could you tell me what the eclipse SDK is?  When I DLed eclipse Java developer, did it come with?

Comment: I wish I could, I was only raising the question for discussion hoping someone more familiar with Eclipse would chime in.  I am out of my knowledge field here cause its been years since I did any plug-in work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using Eclipse Luna.  I followed the path to what File->Import... and looked at the dialog.  I did not see the plug-in development.

If you go to the previous  version, Eclipse Kepler, you will see it there.
http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2

I've found Eclipse documentation to be written for one version, and then Eclipse will make major changes in subsequent versions.  Good luck on your plugin.